# Detect when Remote Desktop Connection is starting?

Tags: c++, windows, connection, desktop

Is there any way to detect when a Remote Desktop Connection is starting on a Windows machine?

For example, I'd like to have a c++ application print "WARNING: RDC Connection incoming" as soon as Windodws detects that a RDC connection has been initialized.

Is there some sort of system event that is called when RDC connects?

Comment: check this [link] (https://ithompson.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/tracking-rdp-logons/) for a solution based on Event log monitoring

Answer (score 0):

you can create a thread that will keep asking if a remote connection is opened right now every 500 ms,you can find how to do it right [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380798(v=vs.85).aspx).

you still might not caught it in time so you can check which TCP ports get open every small interval of time, you can use GetTcpTable2 for this look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406(v=vs.85).aspx.
specificly you should check the state of the port.
since the first thing that happen in a remote connection is the port changing is state you should catch it in time.
The RDP port is 3389.